# Allow IAM user to access single, access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created IAM policy and assigned to IAM user.

Please find the policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testingbucket00"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testingbucket00/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I unchecked "Block new public bucket policies" for s3 bucket testingbucket00.

I tried login aws console using IAM user listing all buckets, but showing "Access as Error".

I want to assign a single bucket to IAM user, please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this IAM user sees 'Error' as the Access value on s3 console, he has access given in the policy document to the bucket 'testingbucket00'.

However, if it is required to see the correct Access value, this IAM user needs to have permission to read bucket permissions.
Add below permissions to the actions of the first (VisualEditor1) statement.

`"s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
"s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
"s3:GetBucketAcl",
"s3:GetBucketPolicy",
"s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus"`

Comment: Thank you Jayawardana.. Now error has gone, and also i want IAM user restrict to only one bucket  'testingbucket00', he shouldn't see other buckets. Can you please help on this.

Comment: @narasimhaawsvayala Restricting non-permitted buckets is NOT possible. You must grant `ListAllMyBuckets` and `GetBucketLocation` to locate the bucket which has permission. However this allow list all the available buckets. Still they cannot access those as they don't have permissions.